# Less OR operator

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to have fallback variable if other is 'undefined'.
As in the following example:

```
@defColor = '#fff';
@setColor = '';

.selector {
   color: @setColor || @defColor;
}
```

For which the above case should return:

```
.selector {
   color: #fff;
}
```

And when `setColor` is not empty, it will use it:

```
@defColor = '#fff';
@setColor = '#000';

.selector {
   color: @setColor || @defColor;
}
```

Which will return:

```
.selector {
   color: #000;
}
```

I know the following will work:

```
.selector {
   color: @defColor;
   color: @setColor;
}
```

But it looks wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say `undefined`, are you talking about an empty string? Or fully absent from the code/unset (like undefined in a scripting language)? What about invalid values, e.g. `color: #zzz`? I think checking for an empty string is possible, but any more than that is going to get far more complex than it's worth.

Comment: ```undefined```, meaning an empty string, checking for invalid color values would be nice, but as said, maybe overly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work using LESS's logical `if` ([documentation](https://lesscss.org/functions/#logical-functions-if)) and `iscolor` ([documentation](https://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-iscolor)) functions:

```
@defColor: #fff;
@setColor: '';

.selector {
   color: if(iscolor(@setColor), @setColor, @defColor);
}
```

It's worth noting that `"#fff"` is interpreted as a string not a color, so you need to leave out the quotation marks when defining your color variables for this method to work.

You can paste this into LESS's [playground](https://lesscss.org/less-preview/) to try it out.

Comment: Definitely seems to be working in the Playground, I believe I'm running an older version because on mine it doesn't work. Will look to update it. Thanks!